# Why the number of dirty pages too high?

Tags: sql-server, memory, buffer, ram, database-administration

I have 64 GB ram and 58 GB allocated for SQL Server.
I am receiving an email "High Memory usage" basically every day and have to restart the server. Even on days when no production work done.
Message says :

```
SQL Flushed Dirty Pages per Second
CRITICAL    10-16-2016 18:07:42 0d 0h 3m 29s    4/4 CRITICAL - 2788.17 pages flushed per second
```

I checked the log and find "FlushCache: cleanedup" message occurs basically every 2 minutes.

[image]

I checked buffer pool and page count for each database, and it turned out that one of the databases (MEJAMES_TEST which is NOT a production DB) have really high Buffered_Page_Count and Buffer_Pool_MB

[image]

Also the number of dirty pages is extremely high 633335  !!!

Can it be synchronization between MEJAMES ( ProductionDB) and MEJAMES_TEST? 
Or what else can cause it?

Comment: Why is your test database on your production server? What type of synchronization are you doing? What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: I am running SQL Server 2012. 
I am new to this company, so not sure why TEST DB is running on a production.
Also not sure if there is any synchronization happens.